# Counting up using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So far I have a little script that detects the scroll top position and at a set level I want it to trigger a jquery counter. So far I have an array with the maximum number inside `var = eightyS = [3];` then there is..

```
if (y > 630) {
$('.targetS').each(function() {
//counter
delay(1000);
});
} else {
return false;
}
```

Now I've made something similar in C++ years ago (couldn't do it now with a gun to my head) so I followed a similar logic. But this is where I'm stuck. The idea behind this function is that it will do a read out on screen of 0 then 1 then 2 then 3. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `setInterval()` which executes a function ever second such as below:

```
var count = 0;
var interval = setInterval(function(){
  count++;
  $('#counter').text(count);
}, 1000);
```

I've created a quick [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5hhj5nuh/1/)

You should be able to wrap this in to your code fairly easily. You may also want to use `clearInterval(interval)` to stop the function executing when you scroll back up the page; or when you get in to your `else` block, which would have the same effect. I've added a `clearInterval()` example to the JSFiddle on click of the stop link. You'll need to make sure the `interval` variable is in scope when clearing it.